# How can I limit the decimal points of a float variable in my c++ code?

Tags: c++, floating-point

How do I declare a variable (float) with a specified amount of decimal points in c++?

```
std::vector<float> gradeVector={}
```

Instead of the data type of `gradeVector` being a float (5 decimal places), I need it to be a float with only 2 decimal places (to the hundreds place).

(Read my username)

Comment: Use `int` and multiply by 100.

Comment: You can't with `float`, but you would need a decimal type. However, there is no standard decimal type in C++, but you'll find some libraries.

Comment: Do you want to effect the precision or the display of a number?  See `setprecision` for displaying a floating point number.

Comment: You can't. Floating point doesn't have decimal places, it has binary places, and the two are not commensurable. If you want decimal places, use a decimal radix. But maybe you are only concerned about how the number is formatted for display or printing, which can be controlled with `setprecision()`, `printf()`, etc.

Comment: A link to help explain Richard's point in the first comment: [Fixed-point Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic). It's very handy when dealing with precise numbers or when money is on the line.

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible. The floating point format of your computer is internally binary, not decimal. If you want a specific decimal rounding or truncation, you'll have to multiply with a number of ten and apply that logic towards integers.

I suspect you really only care about the correct rounding when printing/output, because that is the only time the number is ever represented as decimal (remember: decimal, binary, hexadecimal: these are just different ways of noting the same numbers, not the numbers themselves). For iostreams, there is the setprecision method.

If your grade arithmetic really has special rules that are not the same as calculation at nearly infinitely much precision and rounding in the end, you will have to write your own numeric type, probably, that overrides all the multiplication, addition... Operators that you're expecting numbers to have.

Answer (score -1):

Floating point numbers in C++ are almost always based off of the "IEEE 754" standard.  In this standard, the floating point number is roughly binary decimal number between 0 and 1, plus an exponent term.

So the value of the float is (fraction part) times 2^(exponent part).

This does not map to base 10 digits very well.  A 32 bit float have 8 bits of exponent part (including an exponent sign bit), a sign bit, and 23 bits of the fraction (with some cheating to make it sort of 24) component.

Now, what you are describing is often wanted.  And the way you do it is usually use integers, then divide by 100.

Now, these integers themselves can be floating point values in some cases (!), but by having the "lowest end of precision" be where you treat it as an integer, rounding is easier to think about.

For many purposes, the only time you care about it being a fixed number of decimal digits is when you output it.  This isn't always the case; a bank account actually keeps track of exactly how many pennies you have, and won't support 3.14159 pennies in an account.

If you need to do all of your math with a precision of exactly 2 decimal places, store `int`s and when you display it, use this:

```
void print_2_digit( int x ) {
  if (x<0) {
    printf("-%d.%02d", (-x)/100, (-x)%100);
  } else {
    printf("%d.%02d", (x)/100, (x)%100);
  }
}
```

or the equivalent.

```
int multiply_2_digit(int x, int y) {
  return x*y/100;
}
int divide_2_digit(int x, int y) {
  return (x*100)/y;
}
```

if you are somewhat skilled at C++ you can do this with a class.

However, if you only care about what you PRINT, there are plenty of ways to change how you print floating point numbers to be a fixed number of decimal digits.

Comment: "binary decimal number" is a contradiction in terms, as is "decimal number between 0 and 1". The technique of multiplying and then dividing by powers of ten fails most of the time.

Comment: @user207421 0.101001101 is a binary decimal number.  Here, I'm using "decimal" to refer to "." not base-10 radix.

Comment: Bro please I don't understand any of this I AM 13 YEARS OLD!!!